# VueCli3 ошибка при выполнении vue-cli-service serve

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, webpack, webpack-dev-server

При попытке выполнить npm run serve:

```
 INFO  Starting development server...


10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgrade' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'upgrade' of undefined
    at Server.<anonymous> (/srv/.../.../node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:598:45)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at new Server (/srv/.../.../node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js:597:20)
    at serve (/srv/.../.../node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:137:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ...@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ...@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

VERSIONS:

> npm -v : 8.11.2
>
> nvm -v 6.4.1
>
> vue-cli 3

packages.json

```
{
      "name": "...",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
            "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
            "build": "vue-cli-service build",
            "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
            "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
      },
      "dependencies": {
            "axios": "^0.18.0",
            "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
            "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
            "jquery": "^3.3.1",
            "lodash": "^4.17.10",
            "moment": "^2.22.2",
            "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
            "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
            "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
            "vue": "^2.5.17",
            "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
            "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
            "vue-select": "^2.4.0",
            "vue2-dropzone": "^3.5.2",
            "vuex": "^3.0.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
            "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0",
            "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.0",
            "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "^3.0.0",
            "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.2",
            "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^3.0.0",
            "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
            "chai": "^4.1.2",
            "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
            "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
            "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
            "root": true,
            "env": {
                  "node": true
            },
            "extends": [
                  "plugin:vue/essential",
                  "@vue/airbnb"
            ],
            "rules": {},
            "parserOptions": {
                  "parser": "babel-eslint"
            }
      },
      "postcss": {
            "plugins": {
                  "autoprefixer": {}
            }
      },
      "browserslist": [
            "> 1%",
            "last 2 versions",
            "not ie <= 8"
      ]
}
```

Help me plz)